# Visual Studio 17 not found while visual studio 19 is installed

Tags: python, visual-studio, keras, installation, anaconda

I am using win 10 and Anaconda 4.8.3 and Python 3.7.4. Under the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools I have SDK. Below are folders I see:

[image]

After installing keras (conda install -c conda-forge keras) I started to have problems. I updated anaconda, but whenever I open the cmd prompt of anaconda, I see the following errors:

```
C:\Users\MyName>python C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt
C:\Users\MyName>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt
C:\Users\MyName>del temp.txt
C:\Users\MyName>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)

 C:\Users\MyName>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
 C:\Users\MyName>SET MSSdk=1
 C:\Users\MyName>SET "VS_VERSION=15.0"
 C:\Users\MyName>SET "VS_MAJOR=15"
 C:\Users\MyName>SET "VS_YEAR=2017"
 C:\Users\MyName>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"
 C:\Users\MyName>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"
 C:\Users\MyName>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\bin\vcruntime140.dll"
 C:\Users\MyName>set "CXX=cl.exe"
 C:\Users\MyName>set "CC=cl.exe"
 C:\Users\MyName>set "VSINSTALLDIR="

 C:\Users\MyName>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -version 
 [15.0,16.0) -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" )

 C:\Users\MyName>if not exist "" (for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * 
 -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64 -property installationPath`) do (set 
 "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" ) )

 C:\Users\MyName>if not exist "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
 Studio\2017\Professional\" )

 C:\Users\MyName>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\" 
 (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" )

  C:\Users\MyName>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" (set 
"VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\" )

C:\Users\MyName>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\" (set 
"VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\" )

  C:\Users\MyName>IF NOT "" == "" (
  set "INCLUDE=;"
  set "LIB=;"
  set "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=;"
   )

    C:\Users\MyName>call :GetWin10SdkDir

    C:\Users\MyName>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

    C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

    C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

    C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

    C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

   C:\Users\MyName>exit /B 0

   C:\Users\MyName>for /F %i in ('dir /ON /B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.*"') 
    DO (SET WindowsSDKVer=%~i )

   C:\Users\MyName>(SET WindowsSDKVer=10.0.18362.0 )

   C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 (echo "Didn't find any windows 10 SDK. I'm not sure if things will 
 work, but let's try..." )  else (echo Windows SDK version found as: "10.0.18362.0" )
 Windows SDK version found as: "10.0.18362.0"

  C:\Users\MyName>IF "win-64" == "win-64" (
  set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
  set "BITS=64"
  )  else (
  set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017"
  set "BITS=32"
  )

  C:\Users\MyName>pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
  The system cannot find the path specified.

  C:\Users\MyName>CALL "VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.16 10.0.18362.0
  The system cannot find the path specified.

  C:\Users\MyName>popd

  C:\Users\MyName>IF "" == "" SET "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"

  C:\Users\MyName>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

  C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

  C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

  C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

  C:\Users\MyName>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

  C:\Users\MyName>exit /B 0

 (base) C:\Users\MyName>
```

I tried updating my anaconda, removing some old paths in the user environment variables, restarting my system, uninstall and install keras again, but nothing worked. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Installing any GPU-enabled Python library on Windows is an absolute nightmare. There are NO reliable instructions ANYWHERE, not even on the libraries' own websites. So here's what I recommend for your step 1: ditch Windows and go to Linux. Easiest: an Ubuntu LTS flavor, because then you can install the Lambda Labs stack, which will manage all the right versions of everything for you including the hardware drivers (which one-ups Anaconda).

Answer (score 3):

I had same problems. It seems related to Theano. For me, I solved it by

```
> conda uninstall tensorflow theano
> conda install -c anaconda tensorflow
```

If I install e.g. pymc3 which pulls in theano, I have the same problems again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this'll help, but I can offer some advice to try and help.

1. Do you still have Visual Studio 2017 installed? If you don't need it, perhaps try uninstalling it?
2. Is your Visual Studio 2019 added to the paths?
3. Maybe set up a virtual environment in the folder you want to work in and install/update anaconda there?

Let me know if any of these helps, and good luck!