# Anaconda Console throws Visual Studio 17 errors not found while Visual Studio 19 is installed

Tags: anaconda, visual-studio-2017

I am using Win 10 and Anaconda Navigator 2.0.4 and Python 3.7.10.

When I start up an Anaconda Console now in my "base" Anaconda environment, I get a LONG string of shell batch script output lines This started about 3-4 weeks ago, I think it was when I installed nb_conda_kernels or the Elyra Snippets Manager extension in JupyterLab.  The errors center around these lines showing Visual Studio 2017 or a file named "vcvars64.bat" not being installed.

This is a very different question from [Visual Studio 17 not found while visual studio 19 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311955/visual-studio-17-not-found-while-visual-studio-19-is-installed) because I do not have Tensorflow or Theano installed in my Anaconda "base" environment.

I am at a loss for what to try next.  I would like to make these errors go away, especially in my base environment.  It does not happen in my other virtual environments, only when I launch a new Anaconda Console or "activate base" from another virtual environment.  If I launch an Anaconda Console directly into another virtual environment (using the Windows 10 Start button menus), the errors do not occur.

Should I be using vs2019_win-64 or vs2019_win-32?

Is it safe to install vs2019_win-32 and vs2017_win-32 at the same time?  Anaconda Navigator does not give me that option.

Do I HAVE to install VS2017_win-64 or VS2017_win-32, or is there a way to change Anaconda Navigator "base" environment startup so that it checks for VS2019 instead of VS2017 ?

Here are the detailed error messages.

```
C:\Users\richadmin>pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\richadmin>CALL "VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.16 10.0.19041.0
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I am using Win 10 and Anaconda Navigator 2.0.4 and Python 3.7.10. Under the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools I have SDK.

```
(pandas_plus) C:\Users\richadmin>conda.bat activate base

C:\Users\richadmin>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\richadmin>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\richadmin>SET "VS_VERSION=15.0"

C:\Users\richadmin>SET "VS_MAJOR=15"

C:\Users\richadmin>SET "VS_YEAR=2017"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\bin\vcruntime140.dll"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "CXX=cl.exe"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "CC=cl.exe"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "VSINSTALLDIR="

C:\Users\richadmin>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -version [15.0,16.0) -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "" (for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64 -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" ) )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>IF NOT "" == "" (
set "INCLUDE=;"
 set "LIB=;"
 set "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=;"
)

C:\Users\richadmin>call :GetWin10SdkDir

C:\Users\richadmin>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

C:\Users\richadmin>exit /B 0

C:\Users\richadmin>for /F %i in ('dir /ON /B "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.*"') DO (SET WindowsSDKVer=%~i )

C:\Users\richadmin>(SET WindowsSDKVer=10.0.10240.0 )

C:\Users\richadmin>(SET WindowsSDKVer=10.0.18362.0 )

C:\Users\richadmin>(SET WindowsSDKVer=10.0.19041.0 )

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 (echo "Didn't find any windows 10 SDK. I'm not sure if things will work, but let's try..." )  else (echo Windows SDK version found as: "10.0.19041.0" )
Windows SDK version found as: "10.0.19041.0"

C:\Users\richadmin>IF "win-64" == "win-64" (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
 set "BITS=64"
)  else (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 15 2017"
 set "BITS=32"
)

C:\Users\richadmin>pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\richadmin>CALL "VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.16 10.0.19041.0
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\richadmin>popd

C:\Users\richadmin>IF "" == "" SET "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"

C:\Users\richadmin>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

C:\Users\richadmin>exit /B 0

C:\Users\richadmin>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\Users\richadmin>SET MSSdk=1

C:\Users\richadmin>SET "VS_VERSION=16.0"

C:\Users\richadmin>SET "VS_MAJOR=16"

C:\Users\richadmin>SET "VS_YEAR=2019"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\bin\vcruntime140.dll"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "CXX=cl.exe"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "CC=cl.exe"

C:\Users\richadmin>set "VSINSTALLDIR="

C:\Users\richadmin>for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -version [16.0,17.0) -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>(set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>(set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" (for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`vswhere.exe -nologo -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v142.x86.x64 -property installationPath`) do (set "VSINSTALLDIR=%i\" ) )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\" )

C:\Users\richadmin>IF NOT "" == "" (
set "INCLUDE=;"
 set "LIB=;"
 set "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=;"
)

C:\Users\richadmin>call :GetWin10SdkDir

C:\Users\richadmin>call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKLM\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 call :GetWin10SdkDirHelper HKCU\SOFTWARE  1>nul 2>&1

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 exit /B 1

C:\Users\richadmin>exit /B 0
```

Tonight I tried installing `vs2017_win-64` using Anaconda Navigator and that did not fix it.  Now I get the same error messages as above, but followed by the error message below.

```
C:\Users\richadmin>(SET WindowsSDKVer=10.0.10240.0 )

C:\Users\richadmin>(SET WindowsSDKVer=10.0.18362.0 )

C:\Users\richadmin>(SET WindowsSDKVer=10.0.19041.0 )

C:\Users\richadmin>if errorlevel 1 (echo "Didn't find any windows 10 SDK. I'm not sure if things will work, but let's try..." )  else (echo Windows SDK version found as: "10.0.19041.0" )
Windows SDK version found as: "10.0.19041.0"

C:\Users\richadmin>IF 2019 GEQ 2019 (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 16 2019"
 IF "win-64" == "win-64" (
set "BITS=64"
 set "CMAKE_PLAT=x64"
)  ELSE (
set "BITS=32"
 set "CMAKE_PLAT=Win32"
)
)  ELSE (IF "win-64" == "win-64" (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 16 2019 Win64"
 set "BITS=64"
)  else (
set "CMAKE_GEN=Visual Studio 16 2019"
 set "BITS=32"
) )

C:\Users\richadmin>pushd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>CALL "VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.29 10.0.19041.0
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.9.4
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[ERROR:vcvars.bat] Toolset directory for version '14.29' was not found.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] In an uninitialized command prompt, please 'set VSCMD_DEBUG=[value]' and then re-run
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] vsdevcmd.bat [args] for additional details.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Where [value] is:
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    1 : basic debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    2 : detailed debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    3 : trace level logging. Redirection of output to a file when using this level is recommended.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Example: set VSCMD_DEBUG=3
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]          vsdevcmd.bat > vsdevcmd.trace.txt 2>&1
```